# How do I prevent to open some files in node js from browser

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

For authentication purpose I don't want to show my main files from the application like app.js or config.js where I have added the configuration setting and business logic there. I tried to use :

```
app.get(['/server.js', '/user-scripts/app.js', '/Config/config.json', '/New/server.js', '/hoop(|la|lapoo|lul)/poo'], function(req, res, next) {
   res.json({
      auth: false
   });
});
```

It is working when open the url like 'http://localhost:4000/user-scripts/app.js' in browser but when open the web application it shows that app is not defined. Please help me to get the solution for this.

Comment: Do you use express?

Comment: Yes. I am using express